# How to repaint my JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, repaint

So I have this application with a JTable in it. The JTable is inside of a JScrollPane and JScrollPane is painted on a JFrame.

Now in my application I open a new windows to add a new row to that table and after I click a button to save the changes, the new window closes.

Now I have tried adding these lines after the new window is closed:

```
askTableInfo(); //a method to save the info in database to table and then save the table to variable 'table'
table.repaint();
scrollPane.repaint();
```

And of course repaint(); by it self. But it still does not seem to update my table in the JFrame.

What could be the issue here?

```
public class AppWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    String user = "";
    JLabel greetText = new JLabel();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));
    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    JTable tabel;
    JButton newBook = new JButton("Add a book");
    JButton deleteBook = new JButton("Remove a book");
    JButton changeBook = new JButton("Change a book");
    int ID;

    public AppWindow(String user, int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.user = user;
        setSize(500, 500);
        setTitle("Books");

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        greetText.setText("Hi "+user+" here are your books:");
        add(greetText, BorderLayout.NORTH); 

        askData();  
        panel.add(scrollPane);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        panel2.add(newBook);
        panel2.add(deleteBook);
        panel2.add(changeBook);
        add(paneel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        newBook.addActionListener(this);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void askData() {
        DataAsker asker = null;
        try {
            asker = new AndmeKysija(ID);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        table = asker.giveTable();
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tabel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        AppWindow window = new AppWindow("Name", 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == newBook){
                new BookAdded(ID);
                panel.revalidate();
                panel.add(scrollPane);
                panel.repaint();
                repaint();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the table you're trying to update and the table that is on the screen are not the same and/or the same thing goes for the table model...

Comment: Well in my ´askTableInfo()´ method I do have a ´scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);´. This could be the problem? In that case, how do I update the allready painted Scrollpane with new info?

Comment: Update the table model

Comment: I edited my original post. You can see there that it makes a new DataAsker, which gets data from Database and then makes the table with  the data. After that the info is saved to variable. I think that should be enought to update the table model?

Comment: First, I would have your `DataAsker` return back no more than a `TableModel`...and even that might be asking to much.  Second, what are you adding the `scrollPane` to?

Comment: To my JPanel panel = new JPanel(); panel.add(scrollPane);

Comment: But you've create a new instance?  Do you remove the old one and replace it with the new one?

Comment: I am not sure how to remove a JPanel that I have created?

Comment: My point is, don't.  Leave the original table and scrollpane where they are.  Simply either create a new `TableModel` and apply it to the existing table or update the existing `TableModel`...

Comment: Allright. I will give it a show.

Comment: I added the whole code the the original post. I just cant get this right. The table updates correctly (askData() works) but the problem is with updating the panel I think.

Comment: Okay, so what relevance does `new BookAdded(ID);` have to anything?

Comment: Eh.. the whole thing is written poorly I admit, It makes a new instance of a Class called BookAdded that makes a connection with my SQL Database and inserts the book with its name, author and the ID is for foreign key

Comment: Okay, so how does that update the `JTable`?  There's no magic connection between the database and your `JTable`?  If you update the database, you'll need to read back the contents and update the table...or you simple add the `Book` into the `TableModel` once your sure the update has worked...

Comment: Well in the code I listed, I invoke the askData() after adding a new Book into the Database. askData() will fetch all books from database, make table model with them, and then in the askData() it assingns them to to variables. If I do a table.getRowCount() after inokeing askData() again, it DOES show that a new Row has been added, so the table Does get updated

Comment: Okay, so problem solved then...

Comment: Well, not really. I mean the table variable does get updated but visually it does not. I do the repaint() and all but the new info does not go in there. It only comes when I reopen the window.

Comment: So I am doing something wrong with refreshing panel or scrollPane I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best method, but it will get you across the line...

```
public AppWindow(String user, int ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
    this.user = user;
    setSize(500, 500);
    setTitle("Books");

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    greetText.setText("Hi "+user+" here are your books:");
    add(greetText, BorderLayout.NORTH); 

    JTable table = askData();  
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    panel.add(scrollPane);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    panel2.add(newBook);
    panel2.add(deleteBook);
    panel2.add(changeBook);
    add(paneel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    newBook.addActionListener(this);

    setVisible(true);
}

private JTable askData() {
    DataAsker asker = null;
    try {
        asker = new AndmeKysija(ID);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return asker.giveTable();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    AppWindow window = new AppWindow("Name", 2);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == newBook){
        new BookAdded(ID);
        JTable table = askData();  
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    }   
}
```

What you should be doing is creating a new `TableModel` from the results of `AndmeKysija`, `AndmeKysija` should have idea or concept of the UI.  You would then simply need to use `JTable#setModel` to update the view...

Swing uses a varient of the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) paradigm

Comment: When the JTable is declared, it gives me NullPointerExeption. Kind of weird. I mean I declared it before too, it is there...

Comment: _Not the best method_ full ACK ;-) Then why do you show it ... it's so bad that it borders on useless (as you well know :-) @Veske - be sure to read a good tutorial on JTable and understand the interaction of table/model, just as mad suggests at the end.

Comment: Well I don't know nothing fixes the problem. The code you showed creates some pointer exeptions. Thinking maybe I should just make it close the window and reopen it, that way it will show the change atleast.

Comment: @kleopatra It's 630pm, I have build issues and the conversation has been going on long enough - I'd also need the code for `AndmeKysija` to make head way...

Comment: @Veske Given the fact that we only have a limit snapshot of the code, it's impossible to reformat the whole thing...